# Histograms with frequency density on the vertical axis

Tags: statistics

In a histogram with frequency density on the vertical axis, could the actual frequencies for each bar of the histogram come out not as whole numbers?

Answer (score 0):

That depends: if the Y-axis is *relative frequency* then yes, it will be a fraction. Otherwise it should be the number of points in a particular bin.